# Using Asp.net mvc razor, how to not have to use div tag to force html output

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I've got the following cshtml code in my razor view.

```
<div class="col left-col pull-left">
    @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.NewsResults.Count; i = i + 2)
    {
        NewsResult article1 = @Model.NewsResults[i];
        <div>@i - @article1.Title   @Html.Partial("NewsItemPartial", article1)</div>
    }
</div>
```

The @i ... seems to tell razor to ouput the data.  If I leave the  out there, nothing renders.

Please explain how I can do what I have below but without having to use the  (before the @i).

Answer (score 1):

You can tell razor to output HTML by putting the text tag instead of div:

```
<text>@i - @article1.Title   @Html.Partial("NewsItemPartial", article1)</text>
```

Answer (score 1):

Razor is getting confused because it thinks the - is a subtraction operator, and it's trying to subtract Title from i.  you could use Mark's method, or you could make it even more localized by putting the `<text>` block around the -.

```
@i <text>-</text> @article1.Title   @Html.Partial("NewsItemPartial", article1)
```

However, it looks to me like you're trying to implement a template output, which MVC already provides a mechanism for, called DisplayTemplates.  You should really use those instead of Partials.

Comment: The whole line should be it's own display template, and the model should include its position in the list before it reaches view.

Answer (score 0):

As has already been mentioned, Razor is considering the `-` to be a subtraction operator because of its position right after the `@i`, which is converting it into a C# block.

You can use `<text></text>` to convert any block (single line or multiline) into a text literal in Razor.

```
@i <text>-</text> @article1.Title   @Html.Partial("NewsItemPartial", article1)
```

Or better yet, for a single line (or single character as your example), you can alternatively use the `@:` operator.

```
@i @:- @article1.Title   @Html.Partial("NewsItemPartial", article1)
```

Reference: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/